# compile and run c++ code runtime

Tags: c++, compilation, runtime

Does anyone know how to compile your c++ code wich you write while your program is already running?

And later i would like to run that code.

I want to do this because I am trying to make a game that woul teach you programing and so the user would have to write the code while the game is running and test it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You'll need more than one program for that! Alternatively - use web-based compilation (google for *codepad* etc.)

Comment: What's your starting point? Do you have any initial ideas? What have you researched thus far?

Comment: Well a simple way is to save the text into files, then execute the compiler commands rom the command-shell to compile it, then run the resulting executable the same way

Answer (score 3):

You'd have an easier time if you chose a language that was designed with embedding in mind - like LUA or python. For C++, you'd have to go for something extremely clumsy and fragile like invoking an external compiler (which is also a logistics nightmare when shipping your game), or something as complex as integrating a compiler in your game (probably doable with llvm components, but...)

Also, for "teaching programming", C++ probably isn't the best language :)

Comment: I tried to do it with python but i get some error with memry access and i haven't found any solution to that or else i would be using it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the compiler to compile and link the user-entered code. This has to be made either into an executable that is then run from another process you create, or as a library that you dynamically load and call.

How this is done is different on POSIX platforms (like Linux and OSX) and Windows.