# Is it possible to ask the user for a function definition in C++?

Tags: c++, input, user-input

Consider that I wrote a program that minimizes a given function in C++.
Is it possible either to ask the user for the function to be minimized or to read the definition of such function from a file on disk and then proceed to minimize it?
It is easy to include the function definition in the code project itself, but then each time I have to compile the code again. I am wondering if it is possible to read the function definition after compiling and during running the executable from a file on disk.

Comment: Yes, it’s possible. Depending on what you mean—are you asking for different ways to get a string other than hard-coding it?

Comment: Can you show your code? Your minimize function could take the function as a parameter using function pointers or `std::function`

Comment: @DaveNewton I am asking that after I compile my C++ code and get an executable, I want some way to give this executable a function which then it minimizes it. I do not want to have one hard-coded function in the code itself. I want to change the function to be minimized every time I run the executable without the need to compile everything again. For example, it would be nice to write the function definition to be minimized in a func.txt file that the compiled code can read its contents and uses it to define the function to be minimized.

Comment: Only for a parameterised function (e.g. a polynomial, where you can supply the coefficients). There is no eval() function in c++. But you don’t have to recompile the whole code - just that function.

Comment: @chrysante I did that already. So the solver does take a function as its argument. I want to give the solver this function at run time. That is hopefully the compiled code during running first reads the contents of a file named func.txt and uses the function definition therein and passes it to my solver.

Comment: You're basically asking for JIT compilation or a script engine in C++. Both are possible, but you need to make your design goals more clear.

Comment: What @JanSchultke says :) What language is your function in `func.txt` defined in? If it is C++ you need to compile it first. You could compile it to a shared library and use `dlopen()` to load it at runtime.

Comment: What does "minimize" mean? Please be specific.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I "compile" an expression in c++ at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203976/how-do-i-compile-an-expression-in-c-at-runtime)

Comment: @JanSchultke Thanks. Could you please provide some keywords or resources so that I can study. I have some experience in programing mainly in Python and I have been limited to console applications that is a set of scripts that I would run in Python. So this domain is out of my depth and it seems I tried to bite more than I could chew! So some resources to get familiar with the way the solution works in general is appreciated.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks! That is what I want to do! The solution there and some comment and answers here hint at some dynamic library, which I am not familiar with and it seems is a good time to read about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the function is a mathematical function `f = a*x+b`, then you can parse it symbolically into an Abstract syntax tree then evaluate it at runtime (look at [symengine](https://github.com/symengine/symengine) library)

If the function is a programming function then you either need a scripting language like lua, tcl or python to be embedded in your executable or you need a jit compiler, like the one in julia (which is also embeddable)

Lastly if you can ship a gcc compiler with your application you can compile the function to a dll and load it at runtime, but this is most cumbersome.